# how can I use object outside of a function in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, nedb

I'm Using NodeJs , why I'm not able to get the value of the **data** in **collection** variable
here I'm using [Nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb)

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var collection = [];
    db.find({}, function (err, data) {
        collection = data
    });
    res.render('../views/Client/index.ejs', { data: collection })
    console.log(collection)
});
```

I also Try **var collection =null** and **var collection**;
but still It not showing data.
i have try all of these but these sill have issues.
[Get node.js neDB data into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240414/get-node-js-nedb-data-into-a-variable)

Comment: Note: "WARNING: this library is no longer maintained, and may have bugs and security issues. Feel free to fork but no pull request or security alert will be answered." - it was last updated 8 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the way that your `router.get()` function operates.  Currently, you have it written synchronously.  Therefore, it will execute `db.find()` and then immediately run `res.render()` without waiting for the callback function being passed into `db.find()`.  Therefore, `data` will be undefined, and you won't have the expected result.

You need to run this as an asynchronous operation.  My personal preference is using `try/catch`, but you can read up [asynchronous JS here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).  That will allow for the callback function inside `db.find()` to finish returning it's data.

An example (may not be working code, think of this as pseudocode):

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   try {
      var collection = [];
      await db.find({}, function (err, data) {
         collection = data
      });
      console.log(collection)
      res.render('../views/Client/index.ejs', { data: collection })
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
});
```

Here, we are telling the function to wait for `db.find()` to finish its execution before running the next line `res.render()`.  Again, this is untested pseudocode, so don't assume copy/pasting this will work.  Take the time to learn asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because the callback is not being triggered before `res.render(...)`. It is like an asynchronous operation. Your callback function can work after your database finish to find data. You can try to use `res.render(...)` in your callback function